# Php Html Double Or Single Quotes

Tags: php, html

for print html : What's Better, Faster and Optimized ?!?

```
 echo "<tr height=\"22\">
    <form action = \"{$URL}/admin/edit.php\" method=\"POST\">
      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"login\"> 
      <td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">&nbsp;<input type = \"text\" name = \"login\" value=" . $f['login'] . "></td>
      <td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">&nbsp; <input type = \"password\" name = \"password\" value=" . $f['pass'] . "> </td>
    </form>
        </tr>";
```

With PHP Method 2 : ( single )

```
 echo ' <tr><form action = "' . URL . '/admin/editadmins.php" method="POST"> ';
 echo ' <td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "login" value = "' . $f['login'] . '"></td>';
 echo ' <td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "password" name = "password" value = "' . $f['pass'] . '"></td></form></tr>';
```

Method 3 : (With Html And Php echo )

```
<tr height="22">
<form action = "../admin/editadmins.php" method="POST">
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "login" value = "<?PHP echo $f['login']; ?>"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "password" value = "<?PHP echo $f['pass']; ?>"></td>
</form>
<tr>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're considering speed, this won't make any real difference whatsoever unless you're handling a really massive amount of traffic. And at that point you'd have far more important things to worry about. That said, if you really want to find this out, you can just write a simple benchmark that runs each for many iterations and measures the time each takes.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Imho You shouldn't print html via php's functions, You could just do `<?php //some php logic ?> plain html with embeded <?php // ?> `

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the last one is faster because php parses the file prior to running it, in makes less php to run.

In any case, we're talking about non-noticeable difference, even if you loop 1000 times.
Best practice would be to use the more readable method.

You can still bench if you want, here's a snippet and its result:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
 echo "<tr height=\"22\">
    <form action = \"{$URL}/admin/edit.php\" method=\"POST\">
      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"login\">
      <td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">&nbsp;<input type = \"text\" name = \"login\" value=" . $f['login'] . "></td>
      <td width=\"15%\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">&nbsp; <input type = \"password\" name = \"password\" value=" . $f['pass'] . "> </td>
    </form>
        </tr>";
}
fwrite(STDERR,(microtime(true)-$start)."\n");
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
 echo ' <tr><form action = "' . URL . '/admin/editadmins.php" method="POST"> ';
 echo ' <td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "login" value = "' . $f['login'] . '"></td>';
 echo ' <td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "password" name = "password" value = "' . $f['pass'] . '"></td></form></tr>';
}

fwrite(STDERR,(microtime(true)-$start)."\n");
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
?>
<tr height=\"22\">
<form action = "../admin/editadmins.php" method="POST">
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "login" value = "<?PHP echo $f['login']; ?>"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type = "text" name = "password" value = "<?PHP echo $f['pass']; ?>"></td>
</form>
<tr>

<?php
}
fwrite(STDERR,(microtime(true)-$start)."\n");
?>
```

The first one is faster than the second because there's more echo calls, if you had the same amount of echo, ' would be faster than "

The winner is still the last one

Result:

```
[alex:rc.d] $ php x>/dev/null
30.108315944672
38.896898984909
28.606561183929
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability in Notepadd++ (The code editor I use), I tend to use method 3. It also keeps large blocks of HTML out of the PHP - it doesn't need to be in there after all.

On the rare occasion that I do have HTML inside a PHP variable, I use method 2, simply so I don't have to type a \ before every single double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are (generally) faster than doubles, since PHP knows it doesn't have to evaluate anything inside them. HTML is faster than echo. So method 3 *should* be the fastest. However, you're into micro-optimization territory here, and I'd go with the method that's most readable and easiest to maintain. In my opinion, that would be method 3 but with short tags, like the way Zend Framework's view layer works:

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="<?= $f['login'] ?>" />
```

Comment: Wordpress And Drupal Worked Woth Using Method.

Comment: @SOliver: Interesting, I wonder when this was fixed. It certainly wasn't always the case, but it's been a while since I've run the benchmark myself.